# Question about the existence of a Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Question: Does there exist any Lebesgue measurable set $E \subset [0,1]$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $y \in E$ satifying $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

I guess there does not exist such a measurable set $E$ but I failed to prove that. Can anyone give a proof for me as a beginner on Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: You can take $E = [0,1]$ or $E = [1/3,2/3]$. Then the set $x-E$ is an interval and contains plenty of rationals

Comment: @CalvinKhor So, does there exist such a set $E$?

Comment: My first sentence gives you two examples and the second sentence, which is the proof, tells you that there are billions more

Comment: @CalvinKhor Many thanks!

Comment: 不客气 $\!\ \!\ \!\ \!\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $E=[0,1]$ and, for each $x\in\mathbb R$, take $y=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then $x-y\in\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$.

Comment: the question is for $x\in \mathbb R$ (but $E=[0,1]$ should still work)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks. I am using a Chinese textbook on Lebesgue integral which is rather difficult and thus I thought of this question as a difficult one.